# A question about dividing an arbitrary angle into n equal parts.

Tags: number-theory

There are many interesting connections between the geometric constructions that are possible using only "straight edge and compass" and various sub-fields of the field of complex numbers. Among the constructions that are not possible -with these tools- are dividing an arbitrary angle into $n$ equal parts, for various positive integers $n$. There is an $n$-th degree polynomial $T(n,x)$-the so-called "Tchebyshev polynomial of the first kind" -which has a zero constant term and is defined by the requirement that $T(n,\cos x)=\cos(nx)$ for every positive integer $n$. One must be able to solve this equation in order to divide an arbitrary angle into $n$ equal parts. When $n=3$ the equation is cubic and is therefore solvable by radicals. When $n=5$, I have seen a proof that the equation is also solvable by radicals -the resulting quintic polynomial is a so-called "deMoivre's quintic" which is solvable. My question is: Is the equation $T(n,x)=c$, where $c$ lies in $(-1,1)$, solvable ly radicals for every positive integer $n$? I feel that the answer should be "Yes" because the cyclotomic equation wich enables us to divide an angle of $360$ degrees into $n$ equal parts is always solvable by radicals.

Comment: There is an error in my definition of the polynomial T(n,x) for which I apologize. The constant term of T(n,x) is zero if and only if n is odd. Sorry about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dividing an angle into $n$ equal parts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275437/dividing-an-angle-into-n-equal-parts)

Comment: the answer to this question is here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275437/dividing-an-angle-into-n-equal-parts?noredirect=1#comment2590058_1275437