# Dividing an angle into $n$ equal parts

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

My question is simply: for which values of $n$ is it possible to divide any given angle into $n$ equal parts using only a compass and a straight edge? I know that it is possible for $2$ and not possible for $3$, but is it possible for any integers that are not of the form $2^k$?

Answer (score 10):

The only possibility is indeed numbers of the form $2^k$.

We use the famous characterization of constructible regular polygons. The $\frac{360^\circ}{N}$ angle is straight edge and compass constructible if and only if $N$ is of the shape
$$N=2^k p_1\cdots p_s,\tag{1}$$
where the $p_i$ are **distinct** Fermat primes (possibly none).

This theorem rules out immediately all numbers $N$ not of the shape (1). But it **also rules out** the numbers of shape (i) where the number $s$ of Fermat primes in the factorization is non-zero.

For the theorem says that if $N$ involves one or more Fermat primes, then the $\frac{360^\circ}{N}$ angle cannot be straight-edge and compass divided into $N$ equal parts.

Comment: My answer was incorrect (and trivially so - it implied you can trisect an angle). Oops.

Comment: @bnosnehpets, you are lucky that you got an answer from a legend of Math.SE! :)

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for the mentioned theorem?

Comment: The theorem (often called the Gauss-Wantzel theorem) is discussed in a [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon), with some references. Googling "constructible polygon" will give other proofs. I also recommend George Martins's very nice book *Geometric Constructions.**

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.You know how to construct the square root, so successively you can do with the half of any of 1/2 , 1/4, 1/8,.....(see the formule of sin ($\alpha$/2)). But you can not get 1/3 of the angle which is, as you know, a famous classic problem of impossibility (see the formule of sin ($\alpha$/3)) and not for the integers you are looking for. The simple reason is that you get with compass and a straight edge only arcs of circles and straight lines  so the new points you can get are either of first or second or fourth degree over the field you have previously got. (By the way,construction of $\pi$ would need an infinity of points of the same quadratic kind and this is not other thing that the trascendance of $\pi$).