# Dividing an angle into five equal parts by ruler and Compass Construction

Tags: geometry, field-theory, galois-theory

Things I know:
1. We can divide any angle into two
2. We can prove that $\pi/3$ can not be trisected. Thus trisection is not true in general.
3. A regular $n$-gon  can only be constructed if and only if $\phi(n)=2^t$ for some integer $t$. Where $\phi(n)$ is the number of relatively prime numbers less than $n$ (Euler totient function)

I also went over [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275437/dividing-an-angle-into-n-equal-parts) problem. But the thing that I don't understand is in those cases they talk about constructing a regular $n$-gon. That is we divide $360^{\circ}$ into $n$ equal parts. Which in my case will be $n=5$. But what I need is different.
I need to check whether any angle $\theta$ can be divided into $5$ equal parts.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to pentasect any angle using straightedge and compass. If it were possible to do so, then it would be possible to construct a regular $25$-gon. However this is impossible by the [Gauss-Wantzel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon), which implies that if an $n$-gon is constructible, then the odd prime factors of $n$ are distinct.

So in general for any $n$ that is not a power of two, there is no construction that divides any angle into $n$ equal parts, otherwise you could construct a $n^2$-gon.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain why possibility of dividing **any** angle into $5$ equal parts will lead to a regular $25-$gon

Comment: If you can divide any angle into 5 equal parts, then you can divide the central angle of a regular pentagon into 5 equal parts, thus obtaining the central angle of a regular 25-gon.

Comment: I see! That means first we divide $360^{\circ}$ to 5. That is $72^{\circ}$. Then again $75^{\circ}$ to five equal parts. and altogether we have divided 360 degrees into twenty five parts.  Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, that would be the method to construct a $n^2$-gon, though a pentagon can be constructed without requiring pentasection.