# Divide any given angle into $n$ equal parts using paper folding

Tags: geometry, galois-theory, geometric-construction, galois-extensions

I have known that it is possible to trisect an arbitrary angle by Hisashi Abe's method. Of course, it is easy to divide an angle into two or four equal parts using paper folding.

My question is whether or not it is possible to divide an arbitrary angle into $n$ equal parts in which $n \ge 5$.

Regarding this question, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275437/dividing-an-angle-into-n-equal-parts) is a similar one but it only considers compass and straightedge construction.

Comment: In general no, the field of numbers that can be constructed by folding is sometimes refered as "Origami-constructible numbers" which turns out to be a field that does not contain all roots of unity

Comment: For $n=5$, see [here](https://langorigami.com/article/angle-quintisection/).